# Is Captcha Typing Halal or Haram?

Tags: halal-haram

In my research about the answer to this question, a lot came up about captcha typing being unethical as it is used by spammers/hackers, etc. I want to know whether it is halal or haram to earn doing captcha typing?

Comment: Captcha is not used by hackers. It is used against them. If it is not used, for example, they can spam a lot of numbers to find someone's password. So it is necessary for people's safety. You might want to clarify your question if I didn't get your meaning.

Comment: Actually, my question is not regarding the captcha itself but captcha typing. In other words, is the CAPTCHA TYPING WORK halal or haram?